# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sideDrawer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using nativescript with angular for an android app.I want to implement a sidedrawer on my HomeComponent.Component is loaded well but sidedrawer is not opening after clicking opendrawer button and error

> .   ERROR TypeError: Cannot 
>        read property 'sideDrawer' 
>        of undefined
>        JS: ERROR CONTEXT {
>        JS:   "view": {
>        JS:     "def": {
>        JS:       "nodeFlags": 
>        773249045,
>        JS:       "rootNodeFlags": 
>        704643073,
>        JS:
>        "nodeMatchedQueries": 4,
>       JS:       "flags": 0,
>       JS:       "nodes": [
>       JS:         {
>       JS:           "nodeIndex": 
>       0,
>       JS:           "parent": 
>       null,
>       JS:
>       "renderParent": null,
>       JS:
>       "bindingIndex": 0,
>       JS:
>       "outputIndex": 0,
>       JS:           "checkIndex": 
>       -1,
>       JS:           "flags": 
>       67.....

occurs.

Below are the code for **home.component.ts:**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
import { ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import * as ApplicationSettings from "@nativescript/core/application-settings";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { FirebaseService } from "../../services/firebase.service";
import {NativeScriptCommonModule} from "nativescript-angular/common";
//import{Subscription} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { ObservableArray } from "@nativescript/core/data/observable-array/observable-array";
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "RR-secure",
    templateUrl: "home.component.html",
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent, { static: false }) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;

    public constructor(private router: RouterExtensions,
        private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { 

        }
        public datas$:Observable<any>;
    public ngOnInit() {

        if(!ApplicationSettings.getBoolean("authenticated", false)) {
            this.router.navigate(["/login"], { clearHistory: true });
        }; 

        this.datas$=<any>this.firebaseService.getMyWishList();
    }
    public logout() {
        ApplicationSettings.remove("authenticated");
        this.router.navigate(["/login"], { clearHistory: true });
      }
      onOpenDrawerTap() {
        this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }
    onCloseDrawerTap() {
        this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}
```

code for **home.component.html:**

```
<ActionBar>
    <GridLayout tkMainContent>
        <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" fontSize="13"
            padding="1"></Label>
        <Button text="Open Drawer" (tap)="onOpenDrawerTap()" margin="0"
            style="horizontal-align: left"></Button>
    </GridLayout>
</ActionBar>      


<GridLayout rows="*" height="1500px">
    <RadSideDrawer>
        <StackLayout tkDrawerContent backgroundColor="gray">
            <StackLayout height="56"
                style="text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">
                <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label text="Primary" padding="10"
                    backgroundColor="lightgray"></Label>
                <Label text="Social" padding="10"></Label>
                <Label text="Promotions" padding="10"></Label>
                <Label text="Labels" padding="10" backgroundColor="lightgray">
                </Label>
                <Label text="Important" padding="10"></Label>
                <Label text="Starred" padding="10"></Label>
                <Label text="Sent Mail" padding="10"></Label>
                <Label text="Drafts" padding="10"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label text="Close" color="lightgray" padding="10"
                style="horizontal-align: center" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>

    </RadSideDrawer>
</GridLayout>


<StackLayout class="card">
    <ListView [items]="datas$ | async"  height="300">
        <GridLayout>
            <ng-template let-item="item">                  
                <GridLayout columns="auto,*,auto">

                    <Label class="m-5"   col="1" [text]="item.id"></Label>
                </GridLayout>                 
            </ng-template>
        </GridLayout>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Also this code works on nsplayground.what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you share a Github sample project to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Manoj thanks for reply.I have solved the issue.Actually I had wrong and incomplete imports.